# opcheckout response text html is null

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout

I'm having a trouble with the opcheckout process.
When all the steps are loaded I can see the payment methods but in the moment that goes from shipping method to payment method in the transport.response I got html null

```
{"goto_section":"payment","update_section":{"name":"payment-method","html":null}}
```

So my question is from where got the html? 
Because I replaced the opcheckout.js with the copy that I have in local (works correctly in local) and still have the same error.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Debugging OnepageController

```
public function saveShippingMethodAction(){}
```

In this part

```
$result['update_section'] = array( 
              'name' => 'payment-method', 
              'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
);
```

html contains the payment methods.

But in this part

`Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));`

There's nothing in the html part

Comment: My html wasn't enterely UTF-8 for some things in spanish so the jsonencode isn't working.

Comment: Ahh, interesting. Good to know. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not enough information to be sure. What version of Magento are you running?

Start by tracing your request in the controller, `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php`, see the `saveShippingMethodAction` method:

```
...
$result['update_section'] = array(
    'name' => 'payment-method',
    'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
);
...
```

Follow the `_getPaymentMethodsHtml` method, and you'll see that the layout handle `checkout_onepage_paymentmethod` is loaded. If your `html` value is `null`, then the layout must be failing on the call for `$layout->getOutput()`.

See this answer for a tip on how to debug that point:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2718199/1442685

And keep digging from there.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction, I been checking and actually html has something so I don't know why later is null. 
I'm gonna keep debuggin.
My Magento version is 1.12 EE and it was working, and my local copy also is working.